# FTP-connections error after a while

Tags: php, iframe, ftp

I have files that are continuously updating with information via FTP. In my "index.php"(on another site) I've got 3 different iframes. In each of these iframes, there is a PHP file that's reloaded by a defined time (for example every third second). Now these three PHP files each separately open a connection to the FTP, in the beginning of the file, then the content in the files located on the FTP is read. And then at the end of file they close the FTP connection.

This works well until after a while the error code starts to pop-up.

The error is:

**ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource**

I suspect that the maximum number of open connections have been overridden, but since I closed the FTP connection every time I opened it shouldn't be possible right?  Anyone have an idea how I can stop this "bug"?

An example of one of the php files in one of the iframe:

```
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000)
function myTimer()
 {
location.reload();
}
</script>
<?php
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_adress); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
  echo "FTP connection has failed!";
  exit; 
}else{
  echo "FTP connected";
}

//Collect contents from FTP
if(ftp_close($conn_id)){
 echo "FTP-closed";
}else{
 echo "FTP did not closed";
}
?>
```

Comment: each reload would be a completely SEPARATE http request, leading to a new php being invoked to run your ftp command. unless you've got something funky going on on the server, the end of the php script should also be the end of the ftp connection established by that script.

Comment: Is this not separate http requset? Since they are in iframes?

Comment: yes. you'd have 3 iframes running 3 http requests running 3 php scripts, which would have a total of 3 ftp connections going.

Comment: But that will create three open connections which it can handle in the beginning so I don't think that's a problem (to have three connections  open at the same time). Or was that something else you had in mind?

Comment: did you check if the ftp server has a rate limiter? Maybe you're not allowed to log in more then X times every Y minutes or whatever.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I can see by using TCPView that the number of connections to the FTP is increasing steadily. Is there any way do kill this connection? I thought ftp_close($conn_id) did this (yes it always put out "FTP-closed". Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you didn't just say `the error code starts to pop-up` but tell us *what* error is shown. Printing `$login_result` on failure might help as well. That said, many FTP servers protect against DOS attacks by limiting how often the same IP, or the same user, can connect in a given amount of time. You're likely to trigger this if you have an average of 1 login per second.

Comment: Yes, I forgott to post the error code sorry for that, the error code is " ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource". 

But some times the error pup-up and then disappear.

Comment: I have now checked and it seems that there is no limitation of the same IP.